# terra::classify preserves cutpoints and uses them as class names in terra::as.polygon

Tags: r, spatial, terra

Here is some code to show the issue:

### 1 -- reclassify a raster

establish a vector of class limits

```
class.limits

#[1] 45.16490 50.12986 51.40991 52.68021 54.00000 55.42731 57.71864 60.14900 69.57393
```

use these to classify

```
class(sg.crop)
#[1] "SpatRaster"
#attr(,"package")
#[1] "terra"

sg.class <- terra::classify(sg.crop, rcl=class.limits)
```

see the reclassified values:

```
table(values(sg.class))

#  0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7
#747 1164 1054  829  607  772  770  937
```

So far, so good... but notice:

```
levels(sg.class$class)

#[[1]]
#[1] "(45.164902–50.12986]"  "(50.12986–51.409912]"  "(51.409912–52.68021]"  "(52.68021–54]"         "(54–55.427315]" 
#[6] "(55.427315–57.718636]" "(57.718636–60.148998]" "(60.148998–69.573929]"
```

**The class limits are kept as reference.**  And, trying to change the names by assigning to this vector does not work:

```
levels(sg.class$class)[[1]] <- 1:8
#Error: [subset] undefined layer(s) selected: deepcopy
```

I don't know what this means. But here comes the problem:

### 2 - Polygonize the classified map

```
sg.poly <- terra::as.polygons(sg.class, values = TRUE, dissolve=TRUE)
values(sg.poly)
#                 class    
#1  (45.164902–50.12986]
#2  (50.12986–51.409912]
#3  (51.409912–52.68021]
#4         (52.68021–54]
#5        (54–55.427315]
#6 (55.427315–57.718636]
#7 (57.718636–60.148998]
#8 (60.148998–69.573929]
```

**So now the polygonized raster has labels that are the class limits, not the classes**, which were the values returned by

```
terra::classify.
```

And I can not figure out how to change these.  It seems to me that the class labels, not the cutpoint values, should be the values of the polygons.  And I am fairly sure it was this way about a year ago when I first ran this analysis.

Answer (score 2):

Here is some example data (from `?classify`)

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(ncols=10, nrows=10, names="test")
values(r) <- (0:99)/99
breaks <- c(0, 0.25, 0.5, 1)
x <- classify(r, breaks, include.lowest=TRUE)
```

You can create polygons and add variables of interest

```
p <- as.polygons(x) 
p$breaks <- breaks[-1]
p$ID <- 1:nrow(p)

values(p)
#        test breaks ID
#1   [0–0.25]   0.25  1
#2 (0.25–0.5]   0.50  2
#3    (0.5–1]   1.00  3
```

You can also remove the categories from the SpatRaster like this:

```
 levels(x) <- NULL
 as.polygons(x)
 #class       : SpatVector 
 #geometry    : polygons 
 #dimensions  : 3, 1  (geometries, attributes)
 #extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
 #coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 
 #names       :  test
 #type        : <int>
 #values      :     0
 #                  1
 #                  2
```

Comment: Thank you Robert for the quick response. I had missed the idea of levels(x) <- NULL.  And I now see how I could add the IDs to the polygons. Again, thanks.